# PC BSD Warden network interface

Tags: networking, network-interface, jails, pc-bsd

The documentation for [PC BSD's Warden](http://wiki.pcbsd.org/index.php/Warden) mentions that the configuration of the right network interface is crucial.

However, it doesn't say what the "right" interface is. What interface can I use there? The existing physical NIC one? Should I create a virtual one and use that?

The aim is to have network access in the jails, i.e. be able to access the internet as well as access services running within the jail from the internet.

Comment: What is PC BSD Warden? For non-BSD folks to be able to help, we need some more context.

Comment: I'm sorry, I had linked to the Wiki page but apparently I'm not allowed to add links? I've made it explicit.

Comment: It seems they are talking about the interface inside the jail, but as my last *BSD was more than 20 years ago, I can't really tell. :-(

Comment: Looking at their webpage, I would ddefinitely ask them for clarification there.